# LessPass's approach is equal "one password for all sites"?

Tags: passwords

[Here](https://blog.lesspass.com/lesspass-how-it-works-dde742dd18a4#.ke2jiwiut) is description how does it works. It is open source solution which generate the password by login, site and master password.

It looks like "one password for all sites". Is it right? In general, person have one login for all sites.  In this case we have only one unknown input parameter - master password and it is the same for all sites.

If one of my passwords will be stolen, the intruder will be able to restore my master password (from site, login, password and open-source function) and then get my passwords for all the sites.

Am I right ?

Comment: Firstly, if an attacker obtains your master password for any classical passwords safe he automatically gets all your passwords (in that safe). Secondly, `If one of my passwords will be stolen, the intruder will be able to restore my master password (from site, login, password and open-source function)` is not necessarily true (there are certain one-way functions).

Comment: This has been marked duplicate, but let me mention that with 2FA enabled, stealing your password doesn't mean very much.  Also, pay Lastpass to become a full member and they will do whatever it takes to help you.  They're a great company.  And, of course, export all your passwords to make sure you can still operate even in the unlikely event that Lastpass goes away.

Comment: Dear @Community, I see you marked this as duplicate yet you did not provide a link to the original.

Comment: @SDsolar, I have asked about LessPass, not LastPass

Comment: Ah, Senior eyes.  I have been a Lastpass user for several years so that's what I know about.

Comment: @SDsolar The link to the original is displayed at the top of the question, as with all duplicates. Also, just so you're aware, Community isn't a person; it's a bot which acts as a stand-in for actions which aren't directly attributable to any one specific person on the site. In this case, I'm guessing what happened was that someone suggested the linked question at the top of the post as a duplicate, and the OP confirmed that the original question did indeed answer their question.